# Can I use the Ph. Eur. definition for signal-to-noise to determine limit of detection for spectroscopic data?

Tags: spectroscopy, data-analysis

The European Pharmacopoeia defines the signal-to-noise ratio (S/N) as follows:
S/N = 2H/h
Where H is the height of the peak from the baseline and h is the range of the background noise.

Now on to my question; I measured a water absorption line and got the spectrum with low background noise and a clear peak. Can I use this definition for Signal-to-noise to determine the limit of detection?

[image: Scatterplot of absorption peak]

Comment: When it comes to limits of detection, people do pretty much whatever they want. I know this, having written about it in multiple papers and a monograph: #4 on the book list in my answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/410372/247352). The situation in regards to S/N definitions is almost as bad. So you can certainly do what you propose.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes it a whole lot easier. I expected there to be some sort of standard, but if any method that gives a reasonable answer works, then I'll stick with this one. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to be of a little help. Sadly, there are multiple partially harmonized standards, each with their proponents. To borrow an old joke, if you line up all those proponents end to end, they point in every direction. The main thing then is to be explicit about exactly what you compute as the limit of detection, so readers can judge for themselves whether the results are reasonable, consistent with other results, etc. Best of success!